# How might it be possible to move a star?

Tags: science-based, technology, science-fiction

I'm imagining a super-powerful spacefaring race which has the capability to build or modify a star system or even galaxy by moving stars around, but I wonder if it's really feasible.

Is it theoretically possible to move a star intentionally and accurately from point A to point B? How might this be done? How would it affect anything near the star, orbiting and otherwise?

Comment: Gravity.  It's always gravity.

Comment: I don't think your question is too broad but if you want the answer to a specific scenario, be sure to ask about it.  For example, do you want to change the orbit of a star in a multi-star system or do you want to move our Sun to the Orion Nebula or something else entirely?

Comment: @RBarryYoung What could generate and control the necessary gravity?

Comment: The only thing that generates gravity is mass.

Comment: @RBarryYoung Right, so are you suggesting moving massive objects in the vicinity of the star? What are they and how do you move them?

Comment: @RBarryYoung if you mean Komar mass than that is a tautology. But more things than "matter" create gravity. The potential energy inside a sealed box can contribute to its mass.  Also, gravitational waves can add together constructively  and create phantom masses.

Comment: Not going to make it an answer because I have no idea if it would feasibly work, but I suppose magnetism might be useful somehow.

Comment: I think it would "Fly like a brick" hate to parallel park that thing.  I would tie a big string to a black hole and then use the BH as a gravity tractor. :)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

One proposed method of moving a star is to build what is known as a [Shkadov thruster.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stellar_engine#Class_A_.28Shkadov_thruster.29) Essentially, this is a large shroud covering half of the star, which is held up by the pressure of outgoing solar radiation and the solar wind.

Reflecting the solar wind on one side of the star creates a momentum imbalance which, over millions of years, can be used to steer the star though space.

[image: Shkadov thruster.]

Comment: of course holding it in place would still be difficult

Comment: @bowlturner Gravity does that job for objects around stars really well.

Comment: @Samuel yes, but those things are orbiting, this needs to stay in the same place relative to the star or it will just cancel itself out as it orbits.

Comment: @bowlturner Orbiting keeps them from falling in. This is held up by solar wind, a mentioned in the answer.

Comment: @Samuel Ah, so the solar wind and gravity need to be balanced.  Interesting

Comment: Seems like another case of an object that could be made statically stable but will always be *dynamically* unstable.  Once perturbed from the stable location, the shroud would not return to the stable location, it'd either be blown into space or fall into the star.

Comment: @Jim2B In this case, I think the object would be neutrally stable. Both radiation pressure and gravity vary on an inverse square law, so for an object in which those forces are balanced, they will be balanced regardless of the distance between the object and the star. To control distance, the reflectivity of the object could be varied to either accelerate it towards the star or away.

Comment: Now I want one of those things. . .

Comment: While this method is viable, it is incredibly slow.  I think this is likely better used for moving inhabited planets where the survival of the species depends on extremely slow change in the orbital lock.

Comment: @Ckersch, I have a hard time seeing the object as stable.   The solar wind isn't constant but intermittent - even more so than the wind on earth.   The solar wind could blow on one side of it causing the entire thing to turn and the opposite side to fall inwards.  It's a cool idea all the same - don't get me wrong, but it would need to be self stabilizing.

Comment: That is the subject of a 2-volume novel by Benford and Nivin. But their's is fancier, using the reflection to increase activity on that side of the star as well.

Comment: @JDługosz  I believe you are referring to "Bowl of heaven" which I just finished reading.

Comment: @SanuelJackson I think all methods of moving a star are slow.  It's really hard to move 1988550000000000000000000000000kg of actively combusting fusion material all that quickly!

Comment: @CortAmmon - while this seems like an issue, objects in space are near or are of having no weight.  Weight is a construct invented by another construct we use to measure the push/pull one object has on another. An example is gravity.  While orbital locks are considered to be a gravitational construct with decay, it is also known that planets drift and have "orbits" where there is no apparent lock or fixation on anything.  Since the object would have no real weight, this is not the problem.

Comment: @SanuelJackson Please read about mass and inertia.  They matter on all scales, including solar system scales.

Answer (score 2):

There is the law of conservation of momentum. When you throw something into a star, the resulting momentum is the combined momentum of object and star. So you can change the velocity vector of a star by colliding it with other masses (by the way: the same method works on black holes).

Unfortunately for this to have an effect, these masses must be either very large or very fast, preferably both. Unfortunately, both can change the star in ways you don't want.

Adding more mass to a star makes it burn faster and ramming it with a mass with relativistic speed might destabilize it. We don't actually know much about the inner working of stars, so it's hard to say what exactly would happen, but it likely would not be very healthy for anything orbiting said star. Heavy coronal mass ejections, unpredictable fluctuations of luminosity (up or down) and extreme solar flares should be expected. So when any planets orbiting the star harbor life, they likely won't anymore afterwards.

Speaking of planets: Their orbits will change. Accelerating the star in one direction is equivalent to accelerating everything it orbits in the opposite direction, so the orbits of any planets will likely become a lot more eccentric or the star might even lose some planets or collide with them (this applies to any method of accelerating a star which doesn't also directly accelerate the planets).

Comment: Correct, if moving a star that has surrounding celestial bodies in it's orbit, any sudden movement would be similar to picking up a fishing net from the middle when it was laid out flat.  All nearby orbiting bodies based on their inertia would feel a pull into the gravity wake from the side where the star once was.  This could have the adverse effect of pulling those bodies into a cascade of collisions (unless the distance is great enough -- like outrunning someone), -- destroying the star not long after you moved it :)

Comment: Actually a Star is always shedding material, and(!) it is constantly "adding" more energy to itself by fusioning matter. Compare an inflated balloon that you let go of. That expends its internal energy to expel matter (air) and by that provide itself with a propulsive force. @CJDennis answer above is just that: building a "balloon" around the star and with that start steering in which direction the star expels matter or — to be more accurate — which direction it expels **momentum**.

Answer (score 2):

### 1

Consider a binary system where gas from one is falling into the other, as is commonly the case when the larger becomes a red giant first.

Use magnetic effects to channel the plasma (if the infalling material is not sufficiently charged, take care of that first) to fall onto one pole, rather than all around the star. That will generate thrust as a jet.

### 2

Magnitar — shape the magnetic field to interact with the enclosing galactic field, or with generated magnetic fields.  Or, manipulate it to cause a jet to point where you want, and kill the opposite jet.

### 3

Any star with a pair of jets, cover one to reflect the thrust.  That's essentially the same idea as the shroud posted in another answer,  but easier to steer.

Niven & Benford induce a jet in a red dwarf by using a shroud and aim the jet through a hole in the hemisphere.

### 4

Generate gravitational waves at different locations and focus them to constructively interfere near the star, making a gravitational gradient that the star falls towards.

### 5

Use a "warp drive" to shorten the distance in front and lengthen behind, with *the whole solar system* in the middle rather than the typical ship.  As a plot device, you could have the "payload" required to be a huge mass, so that's the way to travel.

### 6

Wormholes.  Supersized.

### 7

Pseudo-reactionless drive.  Convert some stellar material into dark matter, beamed in one direction. It's a jet without the mess.  Again, make the density and mass of the stellar core a necessary part of how it works, so it's not just showing off but *the* way to make it work.

### 8

The matrix.  Hack the database to change the game board of the simulation we call the universe.

### 9

Exotic physics, teleporting momentum.  Two stars can essentially repel each other without any standard force between them that anyone would notice.

### indirectly

Given some means to move an *exotic* object, or that the mechanism would make things inhospitable,  you move one star and have it pass near the one you want to move *carefully*, towing it gravitationally, slingshotting it, perturbing its galactic orbit, or whatnot.

### unexplained fictional physics

Any common SF device like inertial dampening fields, shrink rays, tractor beams... can be **supersized**.  E.E. "Doc" Smith had the good guys move planets using the same engine as used for ships: already bought-in to the story's suspension of disbelief,  just supersized.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how realistic you want your solution you could have your advanced race use **folding space**.

All objects in the universe are moving, probably very fast! So, for example if you wanted to move the whole solar system, you fold an area of space larger than the solar system onto another area of space and wait for the solar system to cross the boundary.

Gravity would most likely be able to cross the boundary too so you'd want to choose two areas that had similar "base" gravity. Also, regular momentum and angular momentum need to be conserved (unless they do something else clever).

So moving the solar system anywhere else within our galaxy would be tricky as it would have to be moving faster, slower or in a different direction than originally. Removing the Sun's mass from one part of the galaxy shouldn't be enough to destabilise the galaxy, nor would inserting it somewhere else. The nearby stars would just adjust themselves a little bit although long term the effect would be chaotic, i.e. unpredictable the longer into the future you go, but still stable or non-catastrophic.

You would also have to think about the effects of a gravity "shock wave" when you first connect the two areas of space, and also when you disconnect them.

Answer (score 1):

I would say using and then destroying blackholes on the side of where you wish the star to be pulled towards.  Even better, it could be a wormhole where the material and light being sucked in on the one side, funnel back out on the other side for both a pull and push.

[image: How to Move a Star]

Opening and closing blackholes is already possible on a very tiny scale inside the hadron super collider. It is reasonable to surmise that at some point in the near or distant future, controlling the opening and closing of wormholes could become as trivial as downloading a file off of the internet is today.

In this illustration, the matter from the star is being pulled into the entrance.  If the gravity well of the wormhole is of sufficient magnitude, the star will move very quickly without having much matter pulled in.

The largest problem in moving a star, is something I would call `orbit locking`, in which you may succeed in bursts to pull the star away from its current transient position, only to release it into another locked orbit or zone due to other surrounding stars and planets in the vicinity.

Using this mechanism, you could open and close the wormholes in bursts, to give the star inertia, and then you could use smaller wormholes in the reverse to slow the movement down as it moves closer to where you wish to move it — kind of like like applying brakes at a stop light, or using inverse thrusters on a rocket to land.

Hope this helps, and good luck on your intergalactic travels.  Please don't move our sun, or if you do, push it a bit closer to Canada -- it's freezing here :)

Comment: I voted you up cause you said "move the sun closer to Canada" and that made me laugh, but your post isn't very scientific.   "Destroying" a black hole?   Opening and closing a black hole?    Are such things possible?

Comment: Give the star inertia? Did you mean *momentum*?

Comment: Im no way an expert on that but wouldnt 2 wormholes so close to eathoter make a feedback kind of like if you had a microphone close to a speaker ?

Comment: @userLTK - information on the current capabilities of opening and closing mini black holes using the Large Hadron Collider -- http://www.globalresearch.ca/the-large-hadron-collider-ultimate-weapon-of-mass-destruction/5442232

Comment: @Magic-Mouse - It's not two worm holes,  it is opposing ends of the same wormhole.

Comment: @JDługosz - I am not positive on the term that applies since the object is already in motion. Inertia is an objects resistance to change while in motion based on it's mass, etc.  It already has momentum because it is in motion.  You get the idea from what I meant, even though the terminology is kind of fuzzy when dealing with the semantics of the problem.

Comment: Inertia doesn't change as it comes from tge mass. Momentum is mass times velocity.  Pushing on it changes the momentum.

Comment: @sanueljackson yes thats what i ment if it was 2 different wormholes it would be like holding one mic to another speaker not making the feedback effect

Comment: @Magic-Mouse -  :)  ..  yes,  in your scenario of two outward connected wormholes,  it is more likely the star would be ripped apart as it's matter is sucked out through two wormholes ---  so more like putting two vacuums on either side of a bowl of pasta, and turning them both on.

Comment: @JDługosz - thank you for clarifying

Comment: @SanuelJackson If you got 2 outgoing it wouldn't be a problem. But since the same wormhole is so close it would continuously suck the particles in to the other + the ones it ejected it self, increasing the amount of particles linear. I base this on a theory i saw by Steve Hawkins in a video once. Where he talks about using wormholes as a way to do time travels.

Comment: @SanuelJackson http://www.dailymail.co.uk/home/moslive/article-1269288/STEPHEN-HAWKING-How-build-time-machine.html make a search for "feedback" and you will get to the part im talking about.

Comment: @Magic-Mouse - two outgoing, they would both be sucking matter away.  The configuration I propose in theory, if the gravity was just right, would pull the object closer but not inside ...  and any particles from the (illustration: right side), would eventually end up back as part of the star.  Since we are talking about a star, and not a planet, this method would be sufficient and cheap to perform.  The concept would be to open and close the worm hole in bursts.  Each time shifting the set to the same original distance from the new location of the star.

Comment: This mechanism is partially destructive but sustainable as the matter will eventually trickle back into the star, and can travel great distances -- even break the gravitational pull of other nearby celestial objects, which if needed the pull and distance could be compensated for, or even steered in the direction you want.  Using todays tech, obviously this is outside their current scope of capabilities and this investigations into other things such as unfoldable solar sails, are what is currently being looked into.  Hopefully someday soon, progress is made more in this direction

Comment: ... as this tech could aslo be used for steering near earth objects with precision -- or with more skill ...  giving a planet or star or even a blackhole a 'tap' to move out of the way.

Comment: PS -- the problem with science as it is today, is they claim that 'time' travel is really only a matter of going really fast, when time is really just a measurement of motion anyway.  To go back and do what you did yesterday breaks this law as the claims are generally time can only move forward.  It is also constant -- but then it depends on gravity (force = speed = relativity), and the sun --- so what about time elsewhere ? ...  all of the unknown universe can not possibly act the way that our limited perception of it can 'see'.  We havn't even really been out there.

Answer (score 1):

With something as large as a star - wow.   Tricky, and there's also the problem of slowing it down once it's where you want it to be.   What would be the purpose of moving a star vs keeping it where it is?    One method - rather slow, would be using gravity assists, flying large spacecraft or shooting asteroids or comets around it, either giving the star or taking from the star, orbital velocity around the center of the Milky Way - but we're talking about an enormously slow process.

Another method might be magnetism.  If we could trigger sunspots on a star (say by shooting it with electrons in one spot and protons in another spot - oh, say, 10,000 or 20,000 miles away, you might generate a sunspot and coronal mass ejection on one side, and reduce them on the other side using the same method.   Enough sunspots on one side of the star would slowly generate movement.  There might be other ways to trigger coronal mass ejections - not sure, but that would be one method.

Another method could be to feed one side of the star with a more easily fusion-able material, such as Tritium, or perhaps a Lithium Isotope, which (might) - I don't want to say it would but it might have an effect like throwing pine needles on a fire causing the star to go "whoosh" and shooting more energy out of one side of the star (I'm not sure the specifics how fusion and whether that would occur close enough to the surface to actually have that effect - just an idea).

None of these methods would be fast - but I have to ask - why would you want to move a sun or star?   I can see needing to if a star was on a crash course for our solar-system and we might want to move our sun out of the way (a slow process to be sure but if we had 100,000 years warning, we might just be able to do it).

Comment: You're mistaking "fission" and "fusion" :) In any case, fusion only happens deep inside the star, so feeding the star's surface "fusionable" material doesn't really help - the temperature and pressure is way too low to allow fusion.

Comment: Thanks, You're right, It is fusion.    But fusion does happen more easily with Lithium and Deuterium/Tritium, so it likely wouldn't take all the way to the center of the star.   It might be possible to create a lopsided burn and small corresponding change in velocity.    How much of a push and whether it would happen fast enough or the stars orbit would even it out - I don't know.

Comment: It's still way too low - the temperature on the surface is less than 6000 K. Even at the center, in fact, the energy release per unit of volume is less than the heat the human body produces at rest - and that's at huge pressures and temperatures of about 15 *million* K. Any fusion that would occur, even at those temperatures and pressures, would be far offset by the momentum of the fuel as you throw it in. Fusion is an awe inspiring energy source, but stars only fuse extremely slowly (good for us! :)).

Comment: But if OP is willing to have some wiggle room in the realistic-ness of the science, you could just say they add some "fusion catalyst" they developed over time, something that allowed them to use fusion at much lower temperatures and pressures than usual. As long as you don't name it, and as long as you can make it behave consistently, and properly think about all the implications of that - it's still mostly hard (at a level of, say, Niven's Mote in the God's Eye and friends).

Comment: You very well may be right.   I said "maybe" in my original answer.   I'd still be curious what would happen if you dropped a whole bunch of tritium onto a star, but that's perhaps a subject for a new question.

Comment: Sounds like an interesting question. Perhaps on Physics SE (or XKCD What if :D)? My guess is it would not do much - it would likely be instantly ionised, of course, but that's just chemical-scale energy release, and there's a lot of matter in the sun. You'd have to drop in a *lot* of lithium to make any noticeable difference (apart from some quick flash, of course); and there's probably better materials than lithium to get some response.

Comment: You're right - Lithium burning occurs at almost the temperature of Hydrogen.   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithium_burning   Deuterium's better.  Tritium would be best, but it's expensive to make.  Deuterium could be collected.   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deuterium_burning - even so, Deuterium needs a million degrees to fuse.  It still might circulate long before it had any effect on one side of the star to effect velocity.  So, you're probobly right.   It might heat up the star but not move it.  Unless it was a white dwarf, where fusion would happen near the surface.

Comment: @userLTK So we have access to a near infinite amount of deuterium (certainly more massive than the Earth) but we wouldn't use tritium because it's too expensive?!?

Comment: Deuterium is cheap enough.   Tritium has to be man made and it's expensive to make.

Answer (score 0):

In theory you could create a magnetic field large enough to influence a star, also if you have the technology to use the fictional science of Cavitronics you can manipulate gravitational singularities on a whim so you could move it that way. What that is going to do to a star's internal processes I haven't a clue, I'd guess it would be bad though. Having got something the size of a star moving you have to stop it too which could potentially be much harder, precision movement with masses that big is really hard, momentum is not your friend when you have no friction to counteract inertia. The effect on the rest of any solar system associated with a star on moving the primary is going to depend on how you're moving it but in general I'd expect it to be catastrophic at best, enough gravity or magnetism to move a star is going to make nothing of a planet.

Of course if you have access to grade two Cavitrons you can build artificial star-like objects anyway so moving stars kind of becomes moot; instead you just feed the star you don't want to the Cavitron to get an artificial star-like object with the same mass-energy as the fuel star only where you want it instead of where it was.

Comment: If I understand your second paragraph correctly, you suggest "demolishing" a star in place and "rebuilding" it somewhere else? Fascinating!

Comment: @tubes Yup a grade two artificial singularity could, in theory, be created that would express mass-energy in a way indistinguishable from a standard star, with the possible exception of longevity, it may last longer than the universe around it if certain assumptions about it's function are true. You don't so much "rebuild" the star as feed the mass-energy into creating an object that can't be differentiated from the star in question.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a hovering material, just put a ridiculous amount of mirrors into orbit. Then spin the mirrors precisely so it's exact rotation speed coincide with it's position in orbit. Where it would face towards the sun on one side and continues its spin so that they'd face away from the sun at the opposite side.

Comment: Welcome to the forum iJbot, your answer shows potential, but you'd need to expand a little to explain why this would work to move the star. When you have a moment, please take the [tour] and read-up in the [help] about how we work - enjoy the forum. (From review).