# Travelling through Flexible Material?

Tags: materials, vehicles

If a tube was built between two planets that stretched and moved as they did (don't worry about how it connects to the planets) and if a set of rails was on the inside, could a rail based vehicle move through it without being crushed and have its passengers survive?

Comment: Rather than a tube, consider just a set of rails with a car attached externally.  You've just described a variation on the space elevator (for which there are loads of articles)

Comment: @JohnFeltz But would it would it work interplanetary with the material stretching.

Comment: Most practical space elevator designs include some amount of flexibility to deal with passing satellites, etc.  But without handwavium, there's no material you can use for either an elevator or a tunnel that will stretch over orders of magnitude of length.

Comment: @JohnFeltz But if we had a theoretical substance capable of this would it allow the car to travel along it fine.

Comment: Why not?  You are putting rails inside a tube  I am just suggesting that you put rails outside the tube.  What does the tube gain you?

Comment: @JohnFeltz The tube is to be used to showcase the technological success of the civilisation boasting it, what you propose would seem less grand and is slightly easier to achieve.

Comment: I think you'll run into problems when the planets are on opposing sides of the sun ...

Comment: @Zxyrra Couldn't this be solved with an propulsion device keeping it suspended above the sun.

Comment: @Mendeleev that adds a significant strain on the material and changes its shape more - maybe that should be edited into the Q

Comment: In another question, we were working out the details of bridging over a star, but some people incorrectly closed the question as a duplicate. Still, you can see how far we got here: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/64926/is-it-possible-to-build-a-bridge-between-planets

Comment: @SRM Thank you but that is my question also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.  With the amount of handwavium required to create a tube like that, permitting travel within it would be a cakewalk.  The material properties of such an stretchable material are far more difficult to achieve than those required for travel.  A similar question might be "If a society could construct a space station like the ISS and keep six astronauts alive year after year without mishaps, would they be able to make toast up there?"

Depending on what your definition of "rail" is, you may need to invest heavily in expansion joints:

[image: Expansion Joint]

We use these on rail lines to handle the natural expansion and contraction of the metal rails due to temperature.

Comment: Thank you, I was slightly worried that it would not work due to stretching in such away it would stop the vehicle from moving, would that not be a problem?

Comment: @Mendeleev It depends mightily on the vehicles.  A maglev train may not care at all about the tracks stretching underneath it.  Personally, I'd be more concerned with how the tube attaches to the planets.  It strikes me that there's more engineering challenges there.

Comment: I have the connection covered as several solutions were proposed here, http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/64926/is-it-possible-to-build-a-bridge-between-planets.

Answer (score 3):

Possibly, but rail travel isn't a very good way of going between planets. If we say that ~1,000km/h is a reasonable speed for a high-speed train in a vacuum, then to go from Earth to Mars would take between six and seven years.

Much better - once in space - to use a rocket and take advantage of the friction-less environment.

Answer (score 1):

## Sure

Assuming your material has sufficiently high elasticity and strength at strain (which is a measure of the elongation of a material under pressure).

However, do consider that two planets, even those near each other can vary widely in distance. Consider that Venus can be anywhere from 38 to 261 million kilometers. The thickness of your rail will be significantly reduced when you stretch it. If the rail stretches by a factor of ~7 as the bridge to Venus would, then the rail itself will decrease in cross-section by the square root of that factor, or about 2.6. So you would need an engineering solution to ensure your 'vehicle' fits your tracks as they change size.

Comment: That is what I was worried about, the vehicle being crushed but if we have the length without stretching long enough for the furthest distance could we have it work without crushing the vehicle.

Answer (score 0):

Why risk wrapping the rails around the sun by going to mars?  Let's go to Alpha Centauri so the orbits of the planets are trivial when compared to the distance between.

Now stretching is a non issue.  Just have that pesky speed of light to deal with

Comment: Most people are using our Solar system as the planets I am referring to I am not however, I assume that at some point you will need a way around a star.